# How do I call pointer-to-member functions from another class?

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have two classes, `Button` and `Game`.
The Game class contains members of type Button*, and the Button class contains a pointer to a member function in the Game class.

```
class Game{
    public:
        Button* button1;

        void init();
        void tick();

        void wantetEvent();
};

class Button{
    public:
        void (Game::*click)();
};
```

I now define the `click` function pointer in the `init` function of Game.

```
void Game::init(){
    button1 = new Button;
    button1->click = &Game::wantetEvent;
}
```

In the `tick` function I want to call the `click` function of `button1`. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
void Game::tick(){
    (button1->*click)();
    (button1->*Game::click)();
}
```

There are lots of other things I tried, but they were less promising than these examples.
The issue is that the compiler tell me that `'click' was not declared in this scope` on the first example and `'click' is not a member of 'Game'` in the second one. Is the issue that I'm trying to access a function that - from the pointers perspective - is in another class? Or is there some solution that allows me to call the function in such a way?

Comment: Seems like (button1->*click)() must work. I looked example here. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions

Comment: Should be `(this->*(button1->click))()`. `(button1->*click)()` only makes sense if `click` was a name in the scope of `Game::init`, but it's not.

Comment: Hint: "from another class" is completely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @АндрейМоскаленко only it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance to call it:

```
void Game::tick(){
    (this->*(button1->click))();
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b662b119bf43af77)

Comment: Can you please add some words as to the why? Meaning, while `click` is not in scope?